# How to get total disk read/write in bytes per hdd device from /proc

Tags: proc, disk

How to get total disk read/write in bytes per hdd device?

for example if i have sda, sdb, and sdc, is there any file on `/proc` that i could use similar to `/proc/net/dev` for networking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found it..

```
/proc/diskstats
```

the 6th and 10th columns are respectively read blocks and write blocks, to get the value in bytes, multiply with 512..

```
/sys/block/sdX/stat
```

the 3rd and 7th values are respectively the same as above

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command to see disk Read and Write for specific time. like for 1min use:

```
# dstat -tdD total 60
```

Value after total is in seconds.